# Here Map Tile API: Retrieve Map tile address from EPSG:3857 coordinate

Tags: javascript, geolocation, openlayers, here-api

I have to change the map tile provider of an existing openlayers 2 application from OpenStreetMaps to Here maps. To achieve that, i tried to implement a similar approach as described in [UsingCustomTiles](http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/UsingCustomTiles).

Now i don't know how to map my EPSG:3857 coordinates (bounds) to the correct z/x/y tile address. There is a calculation example in the [Map Tile API Developer's Guide](https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/enterprise-map-tile/topics/key-concepts.html#mercator-projection) to get the correct tile address for an EPSG:4326 coordinate and i do not think it is required to reproject my coordinates, since map and coordinates are mercator projected.

Also i am not sure what values to set for maxExtent and maxResolution in the openlayers map, maybe that is the reason the UsingCustomTiles example failed in my case.

Can someone please provide a hint?

Comment: In case using XYZ layer is not an option:
var x = Math.round ((bounds.left - this.maxExtent.left) / (res * this.tileSize.w)); 
var y = Math.round ((this.maxExtent.top - bounds.top) / (res * this.tileSize.h))
Requires maxResolution: 156543.0339 set as map option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using the OpenLayers.Layer.XYZ() method ? Something like the following should work :

```
var map = new OpenLayers.Map({
        div: "map",
        projection: "EPSG:900913",
        displayProjection: "EPSG:4326",
        numZoomLevels: 21
    });

var normalDay = new OpenLayers.Layer.XYZ(
    "normal.day",
    [
        "http://1.maps.nlp.nokia.com/maptile/2.1/maptile/newest/normal.day/${z}/${x}/${y}/256/png8?app_id=" + app_id + "&app_code=" + app_code,
        "http://2.maps.nlp.nokia.com/maptile/2.1/maptile/newest/normal.day/${z}/${x}/${y}/256/png8?app_id=" + app_id + "&app_code=" + app_code,
        "http://3.maps.nlp.nokia.com/maptile/2.1/maptile/newest/normal.day/${z}/${x}/${y}/256/png8?app_id=" + app_id + "&app_code=" + app_code,
        "http://4.maps.nlp.nokia.com/maptile/2.1/maptile/newest/normal.day/${z}/${x}/${y}/256/png8?app_id=" + app_id + "&app_code=" + app_code
    ], {
        attribution: "Tiles &copy; <a href='http://here.com/'>Nokia</a>",
        sphericalMercator: true,
        wrapDateLine: true,
        transitionEffect: "resize",
        buffer: 1,
        numZoomLevels: 21
    }
);
 map.addLayers([
        normalDay
    ]);
```

Comment: Works perfect, after i figured out that Tapestry, the Framework used to deliver the Scripts from backend, replaced the placeholders "${}" with empty strings and i had to escape them. Thank you!